# I thought numpy vectorize would be straight forward

Tags: python

I thought it would be straight forward

I have a numpy array A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  and arrays X,Y,Z
Here is one way to apply to rotation on each [x,y,z]

```
results = []
for vec in zip(X,Y,Z):
    result.append(np.matmul(A,vec))
```

How do I use numpy vectorize

```
matrix_muls = np.vectorize(np.matmul)
vecs = np.array([X,Y,Z]).transpose()

matrix_muls(A,vecs)
```

I got this error:

matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

Thx

Comment: You should note this comment from the Numpy documentations: **The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.** So don't expect a speed improvement - it does not convert your code to be like an efficient Numpy vectorized function (which is written in low-level compiled code).

Comment: why do you *want* to use `numpy.vectorize` here? What's wrong with your loop?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the loop. I could just use loop and never knew why I couldn't get the np.vectorize function  to work in this case but I wanted to know why. thx

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with `vectorize` in a long time, but I can see in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) a parameter `signature`:

> Generalized universal function signature, e.g., (m,n),(n)->(m) for vectorized matrix-vector multiplication. If provided, pyfunc will be called with (and expected to return) arrays with shapes given by the size of corresponding core dimensions. By default, pyfunc is assumed to take scalars as input and output.

So apparently leaving this as default in your case leads to an error, because neither input nor output are scalars.

Happily signature from the documentation works!

Here's my attempt:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
X = [1, 2, 3, 7]
Y = [-1, 0, 1, 1]
Z = [-5, -2, -8, -1]
```

Your code produced this for my input:

```
[array([-16, -31, -46]),
 array([-4, -4, -4]),
 array([-19, -31, -43]),
 array([ 6, 27, 48])]
```

And `vectorize` with signature does this:

```
matrix_muls = np.vectorize(np.matmul, signature="(m,n),(n)->(m)")
vecs = np.array([X,Y,Z]).transpose()

matrix_muls(A, vecs)
```

Output:

```
array([[-16, -31, -46],
       [ -4,  -4,  -4],
       [-19, -31, -43],
       [  6,  27,  48]])
```

Comment: You can get the same using `(A @ np.vstack([X, Y, Z])).T`.